# volume between $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ and $x-y+z=1$ using triple integrals.

Tags: integration

how to calculate volume between $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ and $x-y+z=1$ using triple integrals. I need  limits of integration?

Comment: I thing you need limits of integration (I just graphed it on a graphing calculator). I could be wrong though.